# What's the opposite of 不安?

Tags: word-choice, word, adjectives

> **不安** (bù​ān)​
> [CC-CEDICT](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E4%B8%8D%E5%AE%89): unpeaceful / unstable / uneasy / disturbed / restless / worried

Sometimes I want to use the opposite adjective to 不安 (with the meaning 不不安), but I'm not sure what to use.  It's likely not 不不安 nor just 安, but there's a lot of other possibilities like [安静](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E5%AE%89%E9%9D%99), [安宁](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E5%AE%89%E5%AE%81), [安详](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E5%AE%89%E8%AF%A6), etc., but none seem to be a great fit.

**Question**: What is the opposite of 不安?

Comment: It's 安宁, since 不安 means 不安宁 in [Chinese-Chinese dictionary](https://www.zdic.net/hans/%E4%B8%8D%E5%AE%89). 安宁 means 心情安定、平静, i.e., calm and free from worry.

Comment: Consider adding a specific example

Comment: 不不安=安, as in 安啦！

Answer (score 2, accepted):

不安 mean uneasy, restless. The close opposite is 鎮定, which means a person with a stable mental state when facing either expected or unexpected events (can be any mind-stimulating event but usually bad things or news).

The complete opposite is 安然, which means at ease.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on context, it could be 心安, 放心，安心，安然，etc.

E. g.

这件事让我感到不安 vs 他做事我放心.

事情的结果让我心安.

Answer (score 1):

不安,不安心：worried

Therefore, the opposite would be:

安心

Answer (score 1):

不=not 安=safe

so opposite of 不安 is 安

Answer (score 0):

Simple! 平安 (Know this because a Buddhist monk wrote this on my hand.)